# How to SSH to Ubuntu with dynamic IP

Tags: server, ssh, dns, dynamic-ip

I want to be able to SSH to my home computer with lubuntu 18.04 from my tablet computer when I am not at home. I need this access to practice in programming when I cannot be in front of computer.
I live at student apartment and ISP provides Ethernet connection to my room and I do not have any router. Alternatively I can connect to Internet by sharing Mobile data from phone. So I do not have dedicated IP on my computer.

All the instructions that I found in internet says that I must:

1. Install Open SSH server on my Ubuntu and open port 22- I have done that.
2. Get static domain from DNS service such as [www.noip.net](http://www.noip.net) - I have done also that, now my lubuntu updates an ip to noip.net every 5 seconds.
3. Set port forwarding on the router - I cannot set port forwarding on router as I do not have any router in my scenario.

How to set SSH to my ubuntu if I do not have static IP neither a router at my place?

Comment: So if you don't have a router, then you don't need to forward a port.

Comment: But is your IP real or a local? Please post first two octets that is shown in Ubuntu.

Comment: It sounds like you are asking how to get around the school firewall, which is not an ubuntu problem, but is a security problem.  You should be talking to the school IT dept. for an approved way to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at ngrok? ( https://ngrok.com )

Basically run

`ngrok tcp 22`

on your local machine that you want to ssh into.

You will get a hostname and port that you can ssh into from remote machines that is forwarded to your local machine running ngrok.

```
ngrok by @inconshreveable                                                                              
(Ctrl+C to quit)                                                                                                                        
Session Status                online                                                                                    
Account                       Dwayne Moore (Plan: Free)                                                                 
Version                       2.3.35                                                                                    
Region                        United States (us)                                                                        
Web Interface                 http://127.0.0.1:4040                                                                     
Forwarding                    tcp://0.tcp.ngrok.io:12048 -> localhost:22                                                                                                                                                                        
Connections                   ttl     opn     rt1     rt5     p50     p90                                                                             
15      1       0.16    0.04    2.30    2.31
```

For example:

`ssh user@0.tcp.ngrok.io -p 12048`

Comment: Thank you for your advice Dwaine. I installed ngrok and it works. Excuse me do you know how to login to home computer when i am outside? I cannot perform command "ngrok tcp 22" to know the current port when I am not at home, so I will not be able to ssh being not at home?

Comment: Is it safe yo use `ngrok`? wouldn't be slow so connect over `ngrok`?

Comment: @vasilyv you can see the port in ngrok dashboard: https://dashboard.ngrok.com/cloud-edge/status